# How do I check if a UIView is animating?

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics

Essentially if the user pushes a button while my animation is still going I want to be able to adjust a property and then add another animation, but if the animation finishes I want to have it use a default property. Is this possible? What would really be nice is a way to get an isAnimating property from the layer, but I cannot find anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

if i didn't got it in a wrong way. You can use `CABaseAnimation` and call the `CAAnimationDelegate`. then you can implement the method `- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag`. When the animation is finished, the flag will be YES.

Comment: The problem is when you have 2 animations and want to check that both are over